# Handling parsed variables stored in dictionary

Tags: python, eval, pyparsing

Is there a better, more pythonic way to parse and set a value to variable (stored in var_dict dictionary) and get a value from the same?

The code below is fully working, but especially the setting and getting parts look too complicated.

```
from pyparsing import Word, nums, Forward, ZeroOrMore, alphas, alphanums, Group, Combine

def test_grammar():
    number  = Word(nums)
    itemlist = Forward()
    items = (number | itemlist)
    itemlist << ('[' + items + ZeroOrMore(',' + items) + ']')
    variable = Word(alphas, alphanums+"_")("variable")
    data = itemlist("data")
    assignment = Group(variable + '=' + data)("assignment")
    indexes  = ZeroOrMore('[' + number + ']')("index")
    query    = Combine(variable + indexes)("query")
    action   = assignment | query
    return action

var_dict = {}

test_input1 = "nl = [1, [2, 3]]"
test_input2 = "nl[1][1]"

tokens1 = test_grammar().parseString(test_input1)
variable = tokens1['assignment']['variable']
data = ''.join(tokens1['assignment']['data'])
var_dict[variable] = eval(data)
print var_dict['nl']

tokens2 = test_grammar().parseString(test_input2)
variable = tokens2['query']['variable']
index = ''.join(tokens2['query']['index'])
print eval("var_dict['" + variable + "']" + index)
```

Produces as desired:

```
[1, [2, 3]]
3
```

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval()` is often a sign for taking a, sometimes dangerous, shortcut instead of using the language itself to express the solution. Either out of laziness or lack of knowledge about the language. Both `eval()` calls can be avoided.

The first is used to parse a list of numbers which can be addressed by pyparsings parse actions.

The second is just there to avoid a simple loop.

```
from pyparsing import (
    Word, nums, Forward, ZeroOrMore, alphas, alphanums, Group, Combine, Suppress
)


def test_grammar():
    number = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda toks: int(toks[0]))
    itemlist = Forward()
    items = number | itemlist
    itemlist << Group(
        Suppress('[')
        + items
        + ZeroOrMore(Suppress(',') + items)
        + Suppress(']')
    ).setParseAction(lambda toks: list(toks))
    variable = Word(alphas, alphanums + '_')('variable')
    data = itemlist('data')
    assignment = Group(variable + '=' + data)('assignment')
    indexes = ZeroOrMore(Suppress('[') + number + Suppress(']'))('indexes')
    query = Combine(variable + indexes)('query')
    action = assignment | query
    return action


def main():
    variables = dict()

    test_input_a = 'nl = [1, [2, 3]]'
    test_input_b = 'nl[1][1]'

    grammar = test_grammar()
    tokens = grammar.parseString(test_input_a)
    data = tokens['assignment']['data'][0]
    variables[tokens['assignment']['variable']] = data
    print variables['nl']

    tokens = grammar.parseString(test_input_b)
    data = variables[tokens['query']['variable']]
    for index in tokens['query']['indexes']:
        data = data[index]
    print data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Good, I knew there was something obviously in need of improvement in my code. I understand all your changes except the need for setParseAction in itemlist rule. Also the word Combine can be now removed as no longer necessary in query rule.

Comment: That parse action converts the `pyparsing.ParseResults` into a list. It's not strictly necessary because `ParseResult` objects behave almost like lists and even have the same string representation in this case, so the `print` shows the same output. I thought it to be ”cleaner” to end up with just basic Python types after evaluating the parsed source and not storing parts of the AST in the `variables` dictionary.

Comment: Very instructive, I get it now. Thank you for making the effort.